# Problem with deleting a "Page"

Tags: pages, customization

My developer/designer is being a problem and won't tweek changes to my site... changes I can't do myself because I don't have FTP level ability (if that's the word?). I can only make basic changes within the dashboard, like "deleting" and adding content, photo to existing "projects".

I'm a newbie so bear with me.

My question is... If I delete an entire "page" (one listed on the Navi bar of my site) will that screw up any other pages on the navi bar or anthing else on the site?

This navi bar "page" I want to delete contains items and prices of things, but I don't have ability to change pictures and prices myself. SO... I want to delete the entire page, then use an existing "project" (one of many that exists within a different page on the navi bar) to upload new images and prices. It's a ghetto way to resolve the issue but the developer is ignoring me.

So, in summary, will deleting a navi-bar "page" result in anything other than removing it from the site? I don't want to screw up anything.

Thanks. Hope I have explained myself well enough.

Comment: Really hard to say without more info what exactly you are deleting and what the result would be, but you can un-publish posts/pages instead of deleting them.  You can also un-delete posts/pages you have recently trashed.  More than likely you will need to un-publish the page and also remove it from the navigation menu to achieve your desired result

Comment: When you say navi bar, is that just short for navigation, or is there a plugin named navi bar? You could try taking a backup, doing it, and if it messes things up, restore the backup to undo it. How are the prices/products implemented? Keep in mind this isn't a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site for WP development, if it's user support you need this won't be a good place to ask, answers are likely be technical in nature

Comment: mrben522 yes... navigation bar I mean. Maybe, as some others have pointed out, I shouldn't delete the page in case it is linked to other things. So... how about this.... when I click Page "EDIT" I have the option on the right hand side for VISIBILITY to list the page as PUBLIC (where it is now) or PRIVATE so only myself and the creators can see it. If I select PRIVATE instead, would this remove the page from the site view AND from the page name on the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry you're having trouble with you developer.

I recommend unpublishing the page (saving it to draft) rather than deleting it right away. This will allow you to restore the content if any issues arise.

No one can say for certain whether removing this page will cause issues or not since no one can see how the site was developed. This is important.

For most typical sites, removing a page would only be a problem in two ways:

1. Any links to this page on your site or from any other site would no longer work. This effects your site's listing on search engines as well.
2. Any child pages of this page will no longer live at the same url. This may not be an issue for you. It depends on your site's hierarchy.

There could be a lot more to it, so be careful.

Comment: Maybe you are right... don;t wanna screw things up. How about this.... . when I click Page "EDIT" I have the option on the right hand side for VISIBILITY to list the page as PUBLIC (where it is now) or PRIVATE so only myself and the creators can see it. If I select PRIVATE instead, would this remove the page from the site view AND  the page name on the navigation bar?

Comment: Saving it as a draft or setting it to privately published will essentially accomplish the same thing. You will still want to make sure all links and child pages are taken care of.

Comment: Thanks. Alas... the developer has decided for whatever reaon to no longer communicate with me.. won't even take calls much less emails so I have no idea what the psycho has linked it to. But correct em if I am wrong... but say.. if I switch the page to "private" and it DOES affect the public viewing of another page, I could just go back into dashboard and switch it back to "public" and everything would be hunky-dory again.... errr ehhhh right?  BTW... thank you for taking this time to help!!!

Comment: Yes, you're right. Saving it as a draft or setting it to privately published will essentially accomplish the same thing.